# Almost-sure convergence of a series of log-normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, probability-limit-theorems, uniform-integrability

> Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent and identically
> distributed standard normal random variables and define for $n\geq 1$,
>
> $$ W_n = \exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\frac{n}{2}\right\} $$ Show that
> $W_n$ converges almost-surely and check if the sequence is a uniformly
> integrable collection.

$W_n$ is clearly a log-normal random variable with the following moments,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[W_n] &= 1\\
\operatorname{\mathbb{V}ar}[W_n] &= \exp(n)-1
\end{align}
that are easily obtainable applying the fact that the moment generating function for the normal distribution is
$$
M_X(t)=\exp\left\{\mu t + \frac{t^2\sigma^2}{2} \right\}.
$$

I tried to apply the Kolmogorov 3-series theorem and the Levy equivalence, but failed as the variance explodes. I also tried working with $S_n -\frac{n}{2}$ and applying the continuous mapping theorem, but it also didn't work, I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the martingale convergence theorem?

Comment: @JoseAvilez yes, however the context under which the exercise appeared didn't expect students to know it, thus I'm trying to solve it with the standard random series convergence theorems as 1-series, 3-series, levy, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By taking logarithms, dividing by $n$, and re-arranging, we obtain: $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \frac{1}{n} \log W_n + \frac{1}{2}$$
By the strong law of large numbers, $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \to 0$$ almost surely. Thus, $\frac{1}{n} \log W_n \to - \frac{1}{2}$ almost surely, which implies $\log W_n \to - \infty$ almost surely. The continuous mapping theorem allows us to conclude that $W_n \to 0$ almost surely.

The sequence is not uniformly integrable since $E(W_n) = 1$ for all $n$, yet $E(W_\infty) = 0 \neq 1$.